# python and docker for module import errors, which is possible to work for both?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

current i have a fastapi app that i am developing and try to do testing under 2 machine. 1 with docker and another one without.

in this case without docker one, i wanted to launch uvicorn from the terminal as usual

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

is possible to run without issue, with my main.py having imports from another file like this

```
from util import search_card_price
```

with the same thing, i went for docker and try to build it, it will give me this error

```
web_1      |   File "./app/main.py", line 6, in <module>

web_1      |     from util import search_card_price

web_1      | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

what is the best way for me to do my import that works on both places?

my current application is something like for the structure,

```
fastapi app main folder
|
->app
  |
  -> main.py
  -> util.py
  -> config.py
  -> test.py
```

i know if using something like this will work for docker

```
from .util import search_card_price
```

but with this solution, is not working on my local terminal run without docker. i need to know how to solve both at the same time

here is my dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile

# pull the official docker image
FROM python:3.9.4-slim

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# set env variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . .
```

and docker compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c 'uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    expose:
      - 8000
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi.rule=Host(`testing.localhost`)"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8081:8080
    volumes:
      - "./traefik.dev.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

Comment: include the `Dockerfile` in your post.

Comment: done, editted on the original post

Comment: not solution but as a debugging step, consider `print(os.getcwd)` in python's main, and compare the possible differences.

Answer (score 0):

If the Dockerfile is outside the `app` directory, you are copying the directory too the `/app` inside the docker. That moves the `util.py` to `/app/app/util.py` inside docker. You can use

```
# copy project
COPY .app /app/
```

to skip creating another `app` in `/app`.

You may need remove `app.` from the command as well.

```
command: bash -c 'uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

actually it turns out i can use relative import

```
from .util import search_card_price
```

for local run as well, the relative import works on docker but not on my localhost here without docker is because i am using this in my terminal to start fastapi

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

but now, if i retain with relative import and use this command instead

```
uvicorn app.main:app --reload
```

adding app. infront of the main and execute this command in my root project folder, everything works fine for my local with relative import it seems.